# Should I Use It.Is<T>() As A Testing Parameter?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, moq

So I'm a bit new to this testing business, and using the Moq library. I'm wondering about the use of the It.Is() method.

Say I have a class I'd like to put under test:

```
public class ZeroChecker
{
    public bool IsNotZero(int myInt)
    {
        return myInt != 0;
    }
}
```

So I make a corresponding class to test:

```
public class ZeroCheckerTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void IsNotZero_ReturnsTrue_WhenInputIsNotZero()
    {
        //Arrange
        var myInt = It.Is<int>(i => i != 0);
        ZeroChecker target = new ZeroChecker();

        //Act
        bool actual = target.IsNotZero(myInt);

        //Assert
        Assert.True(actual);
    }
}
```

However, my test fails! When I look in the debugger, I notice that myInt is set to zero!

So I'm considering that either:

1) I'm dumb, and this is not how one should use It.Is()

2) There's a bug in Moq

And in either case, how would I go about testing the above scenario? Switch to `[InlineData()]` and throw in a handful of non-zero ints, I suppose?

Comment: I don't know Moq, but all the examples in their docs for `It.Is<>T()` go through the `Setup` class, which appears to be a mechanism for initializing mocked scenarios. You don't seem to be using `It` in that way, and so yes...it seems possible you are not using it correctly.

Comment: It's not clear why you're using Moq at all here. What do you believe you're trying to mock, and why? Yes, it sounds like you should use a parameterized test - but also, learn about what mocking tries to achieve, and you'll see why it's inappropriate here.

Comment: Option (1) it is! Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moq `It.Is()` is to be used within a `Mock<T>`. It is used to match parameters when you setup or verify a Mock call. I would strongly recommend you reading [Moq quickstart / documentation](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).

Also, a quick search of `C# unit testing with mock`wouldn't hurt.